# How to handle partial messages in MQTT subscriber?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho, subscribe

I have an IoT gateway device that publishes data to a MQTT broker every minute. However, the message comes as several packets. I need to recombine these partial message packets into one complete message, parse it and then store in a database. I'm using paho python MQTT library. The problem is that the callback is triggered upon each received partial packet but I want to trigger it only when all packets associated with the same message are received. Is there anyway to do that? Cheers

Sample partial messages look like this:

Packet 1 =

```
{'DB3': {'CH1-01': '243.7300', 'CH1-02': '0.0000', 'CH1-03': '0.0000', 'CH1-04': '243.7300', 'CH1-05': '0.0000', 'CH1-06': '243.7300', 'CH1-07': '0.0000', 'CH1-08': '0.0000', 'CH1-09': '0.0000', 'CH1-10': '0.0440', 'CH1-11': '0.0000', 'CH1-12': '0.0000', 'CH1-13': '0.0440', 'CH1-14': '-0.0040', 'CH1-15': '0.0000', 'CH1-16': '0.0000', 'CH1-17': '-0.0040', 'CH1-18': '0.0440', 'CH1-19': '0.0000', 'CH1-20': '0.0000', 'CH1-21': '0.0440', 'CH1-22': '0.0000', 'CH1-23': '0.0000', 'CH1-24': '0.0000', 'CH1-25': '0.0000', 'CH1-26': '50.0160', 'CH1-27': '3.6400', 'CH1-28': '0.0000', 'CH1-29': '0.0000', 'CH1-30': '0.4000', 'CH1-31': '3.6400', 'CH1-32': '0.0000', 'CH1-33': '0.0000', 'CH1-34': '0.4000', 'CH1-35': '0.0000', 'CH1-36': '0.0000', 'CH1-37': '0.0000', 'CH1-38': '0.0000', 'CH1-39': '0.0000', 'CH1-40': '0.0000', 'CH1-41': '0.0000', 'CH1-42': '0.0000', 'CH2-01': '243.6100', 'CH2-02': '0.0000', 'CH2-03': '0.0000', 'CH2-04': '243.6100', 'CH2-05': '0.0000', 'CH2-06': '243.6100', 'CH2-07': '0.0000', 'CH2-08': '0.0000'}, 'ts': 1637040150000}
```

Packet 2 =

```
{'DB3': {'CH2-09': '0.0000', 'CH2-10': '0.0000', 'CH2-11': '0.0000', 'CH2-12': '0.0000', 'CH2-13': '0.0000', 'CH2-14': '0.0000', 'CH2-15': '0.0000', 'CH2-16': '0.0000', 'CH2-17': '0.0000', 'CH2-18': '0.0040', 'CH2-19': '0.0000', 'CH2-20': '0.0000', 'CH2-21': '0.0040', 'CH2-22': '0.0000', 'CH2-23': '0.0000', 'CH2-24': '0.0000', 'CH2-25': '0.0000', 'CH2-26': '50.0200', 'CH2-27': '0.0000', 'CH2-28': '0.0000', 'CH2-29': '0.0000', 'CH2-30': '0.0000', 'CH2-31': '0.0000', 'CH2-32': '0.0000', 'CH2-33': '0.0000', 'CH2-34': '0.0000', 'CH2-35': '0.0000', 'CH2-36': '0.0000', 'CH2-37': '0.0000', 'CH2-38': '0.0000', 'CH2-39': '0.0000', 'CH2-40': '0.0000', 'CH2-41': '0.0000', 'CH2-42': '0.0000', 'CH3-01': '243.6400', 'CH3-02': '0.0000', 'CH3-03': '0.0000', 'CH3-04': '243.6400', 'CH3-05': '0.0000', 'CH3-06': '243.6400', 'CH3-07': '0.0000', 'CH3-08': '0.0000', 'CH3-09': '0.0000', 'CH3-10': '0.0000', 'CH3-11': '0.0000', 'CH3-12': '0.0000', 'CH3-13': '0.0000', 'CH3-14': '0.0000', 'CH3-15': '0.0000', 'CH3-16': '0.0000'}, 'ts': 1637040150000}
```

Comment: just save the packets to a datastructure and check if all packets have been sent for your callback

Comment: there are serval way something like this is handled in the wild. HTTP for example uses content length to determine if a message is complete or if there are still packets missing. Other protocols use something like a terminating character/message to say this is it. In any case, you need to accumulate all packets until you know the stop condition is met.

Comment: These “packets” are each complete and valid MQTT messages - so maybe you can add a first message which says “there are three (or however many) further messages to complete this missive”

Comment: @luigigi The number of packets received from each publisher will be consistent , so I could check if the expected number of packets are received. However, the number of packets will vary for different publishers, so I would need to re-design the code for each different publisher. That's feasible but I'm looking for a more generic way.

Comment: @balmy thanks for the input but I can't configure the publishing IoT device in such a way to tell me how many partial packets are incoming for each message. The IoT device is bought off-the-shelf, and I can only configure what values and how many values I want to publish over the MQTT.

Comment: Do all the messages in a group have the same time stamp `ts` value?

Comment: @hardillb they have 1 to 2 seconds difference in time stamp values.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a really a MQTT or Paho question, both are working exactly as expected, the problem is with the device publishing the messages if there is no way to determine how many parts it will send or the start/end of a stream of packets.

My best suggestion is to set a timeout after the first message and when that expires assemble all the messages that arrived in that period. What you set that timeout to you'll have to determine, but if you have configured the data to come in bursts every 60 seconds then possibly start at 15 seconds.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the solutions I had in mind. I could trigger a timer after 1st packet is received and then append all the following partial packets to a data structure. I have checked that all partial packets are received within 5 seconds, so I could set the expiry time of that timer to be 5 seconds. After the timer expires, I could trigger a function that process the combined data structure. Is there any suggestions on how to create that timer? I was thinking of creating a timer thread but I haven't done it before, so I'd welcome any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like a very bodgy hack which will inevitably fail very occasionally causing downstream confusion. Good luck!

Comment: As implied in the first paragraph, the correct solution is to fix the publishing device.

Comment: I think the easier and best option right now will be to hard-code the number of expected packets and process it once all packets are received, until the publishing device is fixed.